# Set timestamp in Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I use Prepared statements in Oracle SQL query. I have problem which I don't know how to solve.

I want to set timestamp like using this:

```
ps.setTimestamp(36, null);
```

The problem is that I don't know what parameter to set in order to execute timestamp into Oracle? How I must replace null in my case?

Comment: Either that's a package in which case what is the code or it's a different language, in which case what is it?

Comment: This code will be used in Java.

Comment: You need to post a lot more code. I assume that you're using setTimestamp - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp(int, java.sql.Timestamp) to add a parameter to a prepared statement. What is the statement? The 36th index here means that it is the 36th parameter you want to add? Is this correct?

Comment: 36 params?!? Ever considered JPA? Also, you need to learn to consult the API when you have a java question. As the answer by @JacobASeverson points out, the API answers you question quickly. That should always be the first place you go with any java questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example sets a `Timestamp` value to the current time (with precision to milliseconds):

```
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
ps.setTimestamp(36, ts);
```

If you also need nanoseconds you can set those separately:

```
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
ts.setNanos(12345);
ps.setTimestamp(36, ts);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp%29) in the PreparedStatement class, you need to create a [TimeStamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) object that you will replace your null with.

Comment: +1 for referring OP to the API (which makes the answer obvious).  This should **always be step 1** when trying to solve a java issue!